# Filling ListView using an array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, listview

I'm trying to load huge amount of data to listView. Code below is working but i want to create an array of list view items and then add this array to my list view. Is there someone who can tell me how to do it ?

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName), true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
    int i = 0;
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        this.listView1.Items.Add(
            new ListViewItem(new[] { csv[0], csv[1], csv[2], csv[3], csv[4] })
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you know before hand how many rows there are in your csv, the easiest way would probably be to use a list:

```
List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { csv[0], csv[1], csv[2], csv[3], csv[4] }));
ListViewItem[] array = items.ToArray();
this.listView1.Items.AddRange(array);
```

The way you already have it should be adequate though. If you're concerned about rendering speed, you can wrap your code in `listView1.BeginUpdate()` and `listView1.EndUpdate()` calls to speed it up.

You can read more about that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx